# Github Action Get Workflow Status Regardless of Environment Deployment

Tags: devops, github-actions, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I am using GitHub Action's environment feature which allows to integrate continuous deployment to our project. After setting up "staging" and "production" bound to the same branches, I'd like the option to make it optional to deploy as I do not want to deploy just yet or simply some times just not at all (waiting for a release commit).

In the event I don't wish to deploy, the workflow is left hanging with the yellow running icon while I'd like it to be green because previous CI tests passed.

In the even I just want to deploy to "staging" environment, regardless of whether or not deployment succeeded I have a yellow icon as the "production" environment was not fired. If I were to reject the "production" environment, I'd de-facto have a failed pipeline.

How can the pipeline success be defined solely by the CI part of it ? Would it be possible to retro-actively update the pipeline success status when triggering an environment ?

Comment: Could you share the workflow(s) `.yml` implementation(s) in your question please?